# remembering the zoom state of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, display

I have a 27 inch monitor connected to a 14 inch laptop.

So basically half of the times i'm using a 14 inch screen and half of the times i'm using the 27 inch monitor.

The problem is that whenever I use the 14 inch laptop, I had the pages (Google Chrome) zoomed twice (**Ctrl 0**, **Ctrl +**, **Ctrl +**).

When I switch to the 27 inch monitor, I had to **Ctrl -** once not just for 1 page, but for every single different domain that I'd visited/will visit.

Then later when i switch back, I had to **Ctrl +** again.

it's slowly getting annoying, I was wondering is there any fix to this problem? (Like I was thinking I could save the chrome's zoom state then revert or perhaps something else altogether)

Comment: A new solution to an old problem: Windows 8.1 and above allow you to set a different DPI level per monitor. Thus, there no *need* for different application zoom levels anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the global zoom (for all pages) in "Preferences -> Under the Hood -> Web Content". This option will set the default zoom level. When you change this, any page which has its last zoom level different than the original default will not be affected by the change; to "forget" the zoom level of a page, simply zoom it to the default zoom level (not necessarily 100%!).

So, zoom all pages to the default zoom level, and then only change the zoom via this default, without )Ctrl 0, Ctrl +, Ctrl +.

Answer (score 8):

I've just ran into a similar problem and found a solution that works very well so far:

1. Download Stylish Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe
2. Restart the browser
3. Click on the Stylish icon and choose manage installed styles, then create a new style with the following content:

   ```
   @media screen and (width: 1920px) { body { zoom: 1; }} 
   @media screen and (width: 2560px) { body { zoom: 1.25; }}
   ```

   Where `width: ****px` are resolutions of the screens with corresponding zoom values.

Comment: It worked man! great hack..

Answer (score 2):

This sort of seems to work.  I haven't tried it yet.

The gist of it is there is a default CSS file that Chrome loads up. You can set your zoom level there.  Even better.  If you perform a manual zoom, Chrome will remember it for that site.

http://farter.users.sourceforge.net/blog/2010/11/12/setting-a-default-zoom-level-for-chrome-browser/

**edit:** oops, forgot to paste the instructions....

> Chrome loads user-defined stylesheets from the ‘User StyleSheets’
>   folder. In Linux, this folder is usually located in
>   ‘~/.config/google-chrome/Default’. In Windows, this folder is in
>   ‘%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default’ for XP and
>   ‘%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default’ for
>   Vista and above. Chromium has slightly different folder names [2].
>   There should be an empty Custom.css file in the ‘User StyleSheets’
>   folder. Just add the following lines to the Custom.css file and save.
>
> 1 body 2 { 3   zoom: 1.5; 4 } Styles defined in Custom.css will be
>   applied to all websites visited. The above lines will automatically
>   zoom every website to a pre-defined level of 150% (=1.5). In cases
>   where 150% is not ideal and manual zooming is used, Chrome’s built-in
>   zoom-memory will kick in and on subsequent visits, zoom the content to
>   the manually set level instead of the pre-defined 150%.
>
> In short, four lines of code, along with Chrome’s built-in features,
>   pretty much achieves the basic functions of NoSquint on Firefox:
>   default zoom level plus site-specific zoom level.
>
> [1] http://userstyles.org/
>
> [2] http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Answer (score 0):

One less then ideal solution would be to use two copies of [Portable Chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable).  One will be set with the larger zoom levels, and one with the smaller.  Then use extensions like lastpass and xmarks to sync your bookmarks/passwords/tabs.