# Different default Chrome zooms for different monitors

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, zoom

I am using an external monitor alongside my default retina macbook computer. The macbook uses @2x `1440*900` while the monitor uses `2560*1440`

Chrome text on the monitor at default zoom is difficult to read, and so I normally have to manually zoom it to 1.25x. I saw from an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/312829/remembering-the-zoom-state-of-google-chrome) that one could use the [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) chrome extension and to make one's own style. I was wondering if anyone has managed to get their own style to work properly.

Here is what I have:

```
@media screen and (width: 1440px) { body { zoom: 1; }} 
@media screen and (width: 2560px) { body { zoom: 1.25; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of Windows allow setting a DPI or scaling per monitor. This would accomplish what you are looking for at a greater level. Scaling can cause some applications to be displayed incorrectly also, but is becoming more common with very high resolutions becoming more mainstream.

Comment: This is a great point. Would be great to get a solution that works cross platform (I am on a Mac and cannot take advantage of Windows's DPI scaling :( )

Comment: OK, your question didn't mention your OS, so I thought I would give a suggestion. Hope you find another option.